# Integral from -infinity to infinity as a pair of distinct integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, improper-integrals

In my class we have said that an integral from -infinity to infinity of a function f exists, when a point c exists, such that both improper integrals (Integral from -infinity to c of f) and (Integral from c to infinity) exist.

My question is: we say that **at least one point c** should exist, but doesn't the existence of such point imply that all integrals with a random point x from -infinity to x and from x to infinity exist, or else such point c would not have existed since we have established with c that we can integrate over the whole area of the function f?

Comment: What about the integral from minus infinity to positive infinity of x$^2$?  It doesn't have a point c but it converges to 0.

Comment: If the function is continuous, then your conjecture is likely.